# Prove that $BB^T-2A$ is singular, where $A$ and $B$ are the adjacency and incidence matrices of a graph respectively

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and let $B$ be the incidence matrix of $G$.

Let $H=BB^T-2A$. Prove that H is singular (i.e. the determinant of $H$ is $0$).

Also prove that if $G$ is disconnected, and we remove the first row and first column of $H$ (call it $H'$), then $H'$ is also singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$BB^T=D+A$. $D$ is a diagonal matrix and each element on its diagonal represent the degree of the corresponding vertex.

$BB^T-2A=D+A-2A=D-A$

It remains to notice that elements of each column (or each row) of $A$ add to give the degree of the corresponding vertex and it was mentioned before that $D$ contains the degree of each vertex. So, rows of $D-A$ add up to zero and it is enough to show that the rows are dependent and therefore the matrix is singular.

Comment: Thanks! But how do we know $BB^T = D+A$?

Comment: This is an observation. Each row of B shows that a vertex is incident to which edges. By doing BB^T, you just take the inner-product of every rows of B. If you take the inner product of one row with itself, you just add the elements with the value 1. If you take the inner product of two different rows, then you would get a nonzero term, if both vertices have 1 at the same column, which implies that the vertices are connected.